# Is it possible to hide a (conditional) input in Shiny?

Tags: r, dynamic, shiny

I am trying to build a dynamic UI that reacts to user input. Is there a way that in a first step, an input mask is shown and after filling in a value, I can do some computation and conditional on it show a second input mask?

I am new to shiny and just trying to clarify whether it is possible or not to do this in Shiny. I very much appreciate any help!

Comment: `conditionalPanel` should do the trick

Comment: Also look into `shinyjs` package where it has `hide` functionality